# I need some steps of a functions def overflow(grid, a_queue): in python

Tags: python-3.x

This function must be written recursively. An iterative solution will not be accepted and subject to resubmission with penalty

This function is passed a grid of numbers and an instance of the Queue data structure from part C. The absolute value of the numbers within each cell represent the number of items within a cell. If the grid contains one or more cells that are overflowing, a new grid is created based on the following rules and added to the queue:

you may assume that all overflowing cells will have the same sign (either all positive or all negative)
any cell that is overflowing becomes empty (assigned 0)
every neighbour of an overflowing cell gets one extra item
every neighbour of an overflowing cell takes on the same sign as the overflowing cell (ie overflowing cell "takes over" its neighbours if they were not the same sign)
all overflowing cells overflow at the same time to form the next grid
this process continues until the grid does not contain any overflowing cells.

This function returns number of grids added to the queue. Note, this is not necessarily the same as the number length of the queue as the queue does not have to be initially empty.

Example 1:
Suppose you are given the following:

|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -2 |  2  |  -3 |  0  |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  | -4  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  0  |  3  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|

cells with -2, -3, and -4 are all overflowing
All overflows happen at the same time resulting in the following:

|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  -5 |  0  |  -1 |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -2 |  0  |  -2 |  0  |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  -1 |  3  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|

All 3 of the overflowing cells become empty and spread.

Cell [0,1] with the -5 became -5 because it had 3 overflowing neighbours that added 1 item to that cell, it became negative because the overflowing neighbours were negative

Cell [1,0] and [1,2] -2 because it had 2 overflowing neighbours

Cell [2,1] and [0,3] became -1 because it had 1 overflowing neighbour

This grid is added to the queue

but.. not done as cell [0,1] is will overflow
after it overflows we get:

|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |  -1 |  -1 |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -2 |  -1 |  -2 |  0  |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  -1 |  3  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|

overflowing cell become empty and spread.

Cell [0,0] [0,2] and [1,1] became -1 because it had 1 overflowing neighbour

This grid is added to the queue

Above grid is done, no cells are at overflow. function returns 2

Example 2:
When 2 side by side cells are set to overflow, they both overflow at the same time. This means that they both become empty (0) and both gain one from their overflowing neighbour:

|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |  -1 |  -1 |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  4  |  4  |  0  |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  -1 |  3  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|

both cells with 4 are set to overflow

result:

|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  1  |  2  |  -1 |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  2  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  2  |  4  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|

The two cells with 4 became 0 at the same time, then each of them gained 1 from their neighbour that use to have 4
But we are not done as there is another cell with 4, so we will have to overflow that cell

|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  1  |  2  |  -1 |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  2  |  1  |  2  |  1  |  0  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  3  |  0  |  1  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|

The cell with 4 becomes 0 and each of it's neighbour gains 1 item

I need steps of how to get results of new grids and counting how many results of the new grids were make. If there where no overflows this function returns None.

def overflow(grid, a_queue):
rows = len(grid)
columns = len(grid[0])

```
# Create a copy of the grid to keep track of modifications
new_grid = [row[:] for row in grid]

found_overflow = False

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(columns):
        neighbors = 0

        # Calculate the number of neighbors
        if (row == 0 or row == rows - 1) and (col == 0 or col == columns - 1):
            # Corner cells
            neighbors += 2
        elif row == 0 or row == rows - 1 or col == 0 or col == columns - 1:
            # Edge cells
            neighbors += 3
        else:
            # Inner cells
            neighbors += 4

        cell_value = grid[row][col]
        if abs(cell_value) >= neighbors:
            found_overflow = True

            for r, c in [(row + 1, col), (row - 1, col), (row, col + 1), (row, col - 1)]:
                if 0 <= r < rows and 0 <= c < columns:
                    if cell_value < 0 and grid[r][c] >= 0:
                        new_grid[r][c] += 1
                    elif cell_value > 0 and grid[r][c] <= 0:
                        new_grid[r][c] -= 1

            new_grid[row][col] = 0

if found_overflow:
    # Enqueue the new grid
    for row in new_grid:
        a_queue.enqueue(row)
    # Recursively call overflow with the new grid and increment the result by 1
    updated_count, final_grid = overflow(new_grid, a_queue)
    return updated_count + 1, final_grid
else:
    # Base case: No overflowing cells found
    return 0, grid
```

I was expecting the number of grids made or return value None if there where no overflows

Comment: What do you get instead of what you expect?